# Unable to locate package for very package

Tags: apt

I'm new to Linux and I want to use it as my main os but I got a problem while installing apps

For example I type :

`sudo apt install chromium-browser`

It says unable to locate package

I know it's so basic and did not searched for it too much

Comment: Packages are built for a release, you've not provided yours thus we'll be guessing somewhat (*we'll only know your OS & release details if you tell us*).  For my release, the package is found in *universe*, thus have you *enabled* universe?  FYI:  "*universe*" are where community sourced packages are stored; as they have a lower security factor, plus less support life (*for some releases*) they're not *enabled* by default for some install media.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah it was my problem too when I switched to ubuntu

It just got solved by running :

```
sudo apt update
```

But if you still have problem you may need to open software and update application and change the main server to usa

Comment: +1, FYI: Only the U.S.A folks would get the option of U.S.A in the mirror lost, others might get different servers.